# Django Error admin.E202 'stamm.Workplan' has no ForeignKey to 'enquiry.Costing', Inline-Model in a Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm struggling with the following Problem:

I have created two apps, "stamm" and "enquiry". In the first app "stamm" I have the model Workplan. In the second app "enquiry" I have the model "Costing". I use a M2M relationship via a through-model called "CostingWorkplan" below my Costing model. Then I want to add a TabularInline from the Workplan to my CostingAdmin. When I do this, I get the Error

> <class 'enquiry.admin.WorkplanInline'>: (admin.E202) 'stamm.Workplan'
> has no ForeignKey to 'enquiry.Costing'.

I checked a couple of threads with a similar Problem, but can't get rid of it. Did I overlook something?

Here is my Python Code:

```
# stamm.models.py

class Workplan(model.Model):
    some_fields = ...


# enquiry.models.py

from stamm.models import Workplan

class Costing(model.Model):
    some_fields = ...
    costing_workplan = models.ManyToManyField(Workplan, through='CostingWorkplan')

class CostingWorkplan(models.Model):
    workplan = models.ForeignKey(Workplan, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    costing = models.ForeignKey(Costing, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)


# enquiry.admin.py
from .models import Costing
from stamm.models import Workplan

class WorkplanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Workplan

@admin.register(Costing)
class CostingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (WorkplanInline, )
```

Answer (score 6):

After hours of research, reading and testing yesterday, I found the answer.

I overread some important detail in the documentation for Inline models working with many-to-many models.

The important key is to replace

```
class WorkplanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Workplan
```

with

```
class WorkplanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Costing.costing_workplan.through
```

You can read more about it in the ModelAdmin Documentation under the point "Working with many-to-many models":
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

`Workplan` and `Costing` can also inline `CostingWorkplan` as shown below;

```py
class CostingWorkplanInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CostingWorkplan

@admin.register(Workplan)
class WorkplanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CostingWorkplanInline,)

@admin.register(Costing)
class CostingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CostingWorkplanInline,)
```